# "Script error" reported in window.onerror without cross-site scripting

Tags: javascript, error-handling

Almost every JS error I get using window.onerror is the unhelpful "Script error" message.

I have read everything I can find on this but it is always said it is caused by cross-site scripting, but there's none in my code.

Why do these unhelpful error messages appear and how can I replace them with the full messages that appear in the console?

As a test example, I created a minimal HTML/JS code pair. This is the HTML page, testpage.html:

```
<html>
<head></head>
  <body>
    <script src="/js/testpage.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and JS script:

```
window.onerror = function(msg, url, lineNo, columnNo, error) {
  // code goes here to generate log entry on the server
  return true;
}
// generate illustrative sample error
var jsonData = "";
var data = JSON.parse(jsonData);
```

Running this, msg = "Script error" and other parameters are either null or zero. The Google DevTools console displays the full error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
  at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
  at testpage.min.js:7
```

Any help towards being able to log the full error messages will be most welcome. I'm at a complete loss.

EDIT: Recast to make problem clearer.

Comment: Use a try/catch block around the code you want to catch the error with, eg `try{JSON.parse('')}catch(e){alert(e)}` this will give you the message you get on the console.

Comment: @patrickevans: That would work fine in that situation. But the JSON error here is just an ilustrative example of a much wider issue: why should "Script error" be occurring at all? Would I not have to put a try/catch block around every line in a script to be sure to catch all possible errors? That rather defeats the idea of using a global error catcher.